# MediaHTTPConnection Error in Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm working on an Android app, and I'm facing an issue with the MediaPlayer in my code. When I try to create a new MediaPlayer instance using createMediaPlayer(), I encounter the following error:

```
main (blocked):tid=1 systid=958 | waiting to lock <0x06913f69> (android.media.MediaHTTPConnection) held by thread 56
       at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.disconnect(MediaHTTPConnection.java:173)
       ...
```

This error seems to be related to the MediaHTTPConnection. I'm not sure what's causing it or how to resolve it. I'm looking for guidance on how to fix this issue.

**Please find below the relevant code snippet where the error is occurring:**

```
private fun createMediaPlayer(dataSource: String?) = lifecycleScope.launch {
        mediaPlayer?.release()
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build())
            try {
                setDataSource(dataSource)
                prepareAsync()
                setOnPreparedListener { mp ->
                    mp.start()
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            var count = 1
            setOnCompletionListener {
                if (count < maxCount) {
                    count++
                    repetitionNum--
                    Log.d("TAG", "onViewCreated: $repetitionNum")
                    binding.tvRepetition.text = repetitionNum.toString()
                    start()
                } else {
                    binding.cardStackView.swipe()
                }
                addHasanatToScore(hasanatPerAyah)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Additional Information:**

The code is part of an Android app that plays audio content.
I'm using the MediaPlayer class to manage audio playback.
The error occurs when trying to create a new MediaPlayer instance.
The app's behavior is to play audio and repeat it a certain number of times.
What I've Tried:

I have reviewed my code and made sure that the dataSource provided to the MediaPlayer is valid.
I've checked for any missing permissions or issues with the audio source.

**Question:**

What is causing the "waiting to lock" error related to the MediaHTTPConnection?

How can I resolve this error and successfully create a new MediaPlayer instance?

Are there any best practices or common pitfalls I should be aware of when working with the Android MediaPlayer class in a multi-threaded environment?

Any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!